# Multiple UserControls with JQuery Autocomplete in ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have multiple Usercontrols in my project. Please find below two such Usercontrols' markup.

**Places Usercontrol**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Places.ascx.cs" Inherits="Places" EnableTheming="true" %>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
        SetAutoComplete();
    });
    function SetAutoComplete() {
        $("[id$=txtLocation]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                AjaxCall("<%= ResolveUrl("~/UControls/WebMethods.aspx/GetLocations") %>", request.term, response)
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfLocation]").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
        }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfLocation" runat="server" />
```

**Skills User Control**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UCSkill.ascx.cs" Inherits="UCSkill" EnableTheming="true" %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
            SetAutoComplete();
        });
        function SetAutoComplete() {
            $("[id$=txtSkill]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    AjaxCall("<%= ResolveUrl("~/UControls/WebMethods.aspx/GetSkills") %>", request.term, response)
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("[id$=hfSkillID]").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        }
    </script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSkill" runat="server" SkinID="lg-TB"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddSkill" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddSkill_Click" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSkillID" runat="server" />
```

Now my problem is, if use both the usercontrols in same page as below, only the one in the bottom works, 
i.e., my PlacesUC works and SkillsUC doesn't work, it just remains blank and doesn't throw any error even. If I move PlacesUC to top and SkillsUC to bottom, then my SkillsUC works and PlacesUC doesn't work. To make it clear the last usercontrol in the page alone works. Rest all Usercontrols above it doesn't work. It may be a conflict with ready function or autocomplete function.
 How to resolve this?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" MasterPageFile="~/UI/HomePage.master" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UControls/Places.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Places" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UControls/UCSkill.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="UCSkill" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-inline">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                          <uc1:UCSkill runat="server" ID="UCSkill" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <uc1:Places runat="server" ID="Places" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Edit:-**

**My Ajax Call Function is as follows.**

```
function AjaxCall(url, prefix, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + prefix + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.split('|')[0],
                    val: item.split('|')[1]
                };
            }))
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**My master page is as follows.**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="HomePage.master.cs" Inherits="HomePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>e-Recruitment</title>
</head>
<body style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">
    <style type="text/css">
        .borderless td, .borderless th {
            border: none;
        }

        .checkboxlist-inline li, .radiobuttonlist-inline li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .checkboxlist-inline, .radiobuttonlist-inline {
            margin-left: 8px;
        }

            .checkboxlist-inline label, .radiobuttonlist-inline label {
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 8px;
            }
    </style>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <form id="MainForm" runat="server"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Company" Name="Company.JavaScript.CompanyScript.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdPanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="ParentDiv" class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <img src="../Content/Images/logonew.png" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageContent" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <br />
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 10%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTheme" runat="server" Text="Site Theme"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 20%; text-align: left">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTheme" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTheme_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 70%; text-align: right">
                                        <small><i>&copy;<asp:Label ID="lblComp" runat="server" Text=" Company 2018"></asp:Label>
                                            &reg;<asp:Label ID="lblRights" runat="server" Text=" All Rights Reserved"></asp:Label></i></small>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please put your document.ready function on main page in place of User controls and try. Also make sure that Jquery included in the bottom of master page.

Comment: I tried placing document.ready function in my main Test.aspx page, it still behaves the same way, only the last usercontrol in the page works. If i include Jquery in masterpage, all the pages without these user controls are throwing javascript errors.

Comment: Can you pleas paste complete code of the pages in questions. It look like jquery conflict issue.

Comment: Posted, please check and let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, Finally the following solution worked.

1. All the Function names should be unique.
2. On page postback UpdatePanel content changes, so the events need to be registered again.

Considering the above two points, following is the new code.

**Places User Control**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Places.ascx.cs" Inherits="Places" EnableTheming="true" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        GetLocations();
    });
    var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
        GetLocations();
    });
    function GetLocations() {
        $("[id$=txtLocation]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                AjaxCall("<%= ResolveUrl("~/UControls/WebMethods.aspx/GetLocations") %>", request.term, response)
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfLocation]").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
        }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfLocation" runat="server" />
```

**Skill User Control**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UCSkill.ascx.cs" Inherits="UCSkill" EnableTheming="true" %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            GetSkills();
        });
        var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
            GetSkills();
        });
        function GetSkills() {
            $("[id$=txtSkill]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    AjaxCall("<%= ResolveUrl("~/UControls/WebMethods.aspx/GetSkills") %>", request.term, response)
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("[id$=hfSkillID]").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        }
    </script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSkill" runat="server" SkinID="lg-TB"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddSkill" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddSkill_Click" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSkillID" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update Jquery to select closest control to call your

```
SetAutoComplete();
```

code then all controls will work.

Comment: How to do that, can you paste the code, i am new to jquery

Answer (score 0):

please check this line in your doucment.ready code.

```
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
```

page is throwing

> EndRequest is not defined error

.

Comment: I removed that line and tried, still problem exists, only the last usercontrol in the page works. All other UCs remain silent, no error, no output

Comment: I got an idea, i renamed all SetAutocomplete functions with unique names, then they started working, but once the page is posted back, none of them are working, all UCs remain silent after postback, any suggestions?

Comment: put alert in SetAutocomplete() to check that it is calling and throwing any error.

Comment: Hi, I posted solution, please check, it's working now, thank you for the help.

Comment: Accept your posted answer so that it can be a benefited for others.

Comment: I can do that only after two days, it's not allowing me now.